# Macでcatで出力されたシリアルポートの出力が途中で変わる

Tags: macos

Macでシリアルポートからデータを取り込もうと考えています。

テストデバイスからの出力を

```
screen /dev/cu.usbserial-AI055VOD 1200
```

で取り込むと

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
（以下繰り返し)
```

と正しく出力されるのですが、catやC言語のopenで取り込むと途中から'?'(0x00)が出力されます。

```
$sudo stty -f /dev/cu.usbserial-AI055VOD cs8 -parenb -cstopb  1200
$ cat /dev/cu.usbserial-AI055VOD 
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
He????????????????????(以下繰り返し)
```

screenでは正しく表示されるということは、sttyに何か追加の設定が必要なのでしょうか？
最終的にはc言語で

```
open(SERIAL_PORT, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK)
```

で使いたいのですが、こちらでやっても途中から0x00が出力ていて困っております。

Comment: 典型的には「 `\x00` の連続」 は「ブレイク信号」であり、要するに通信異常です。受信エラーなバイトを無視してなかったことにするか、それでも表示するか、という設計方針の差が挙動の違いとして表面化しているのでしょう。オイラならプロトコルアナライザを接続してバス上に流れている信号を見てみます。今後もこういうことがあった場合のために（特にお仕事なら）プロトコルアナライザなりオシロスコープなりを導入検討してみてください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございました。プロトコルアナライザでの出力は正常でした。最終的にはCのプログラムで書きたかったのですが、openをO_NONBLOCKにして    cfsetospeed(&toptions, B1200);
    cfmakeraw(&toptions);と速度とrawモード用の構造体設定関数を使って、さらに設定直後にtcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);でフラッシュしてから読み込むと無事一文字ずつ読み込むことができました。cfmakeraw(&toptions);の内容を参考にすればsttyでも設定できそうなので、試してみたいと思います。

Comment: @smj320 もし解決されたのであれば、解決策をご自身で回答として投稿して、回答左側にあるチェックマークをつけていただけませんか？そうするとこの質問が「解決済み」とマークされるので、今後同じ疑問を抱いた人がここに辿りついた時によりわかりやすいかと思います。